# What is the efficient way to find nearby places using google places in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

What I need from google place api is to display me some `tag` places,  by that i mean particular category, lets say `school` or `hospitals` etc.
I have came across with few tutorials here

1. [Javapapers.com](http://javapapers.com/android/find-places-nearby-in-google-maps-using-google-places-apiandroid-app/)
2. [wptrafficanalyzer](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/)

both of them are pretty good but it's lengthy, and hence might consume a lot of space. What i want to do is simply `request` for the places with the `place-type` and get the name and location as well and display it to the user.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

U can use google place api for android.

https://developers.google.com/places/android/start#api-key

Comment: That's what I am asking

Comment: that's not the answer i meant

Answer (score 0):

You would want to add type parameter

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=API_KEY
```

You can see all support types [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)